# Swift autolayout multiple views/labels

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, label

I want to programmatically divide my screen into three parts. Each part shall be a label with a backgroundColor and the width is set to be:

```
// Get the device width
self.view.bounds.width
```

The height must be dynamically. An example is in the image below. Each color is one part. The first part (the red part) must be attached to the top and the last part (the orange) must be attached to the bottom. And dependent on the label size inside each part the height shall be adjusted.[image]

The blue part is always 100% and dependent of the red and orange part it subtracts from the blue part.

Anyone have any ideas of how to achieve this? Appreciate help!

Comment: Does it have to fill the screen, or it that just the way you've drawn it?

Comment: How do you want to divide them up?

Comment: Imagine all the three Labels only have one line of Text in them. What happens?

Comment: @ABakerSmith if the red part is 10% and the orange part is 20% the blue part shall always take the rest, in this case 70%. So the blue part is always 100% and dependent of the red and orange part it subtracts from the blue part.

Comment: Two questions? What if there's more text than will fit on the screen? And, because you can't centre text vertically in a `UILabel` couldn't  you end up with a lot of empty space?

Comment: @ABakerSmith It will not fill up, I will enter the text and it will not be that much text. For the other question, I don´t think it´s a problem with the empty space.

Comment: Is this using IB or are you doing it with code?

Comment: @ABakerSmith programmatically.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sorry it's taken a while, I've been busy these past couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this is best to use AutoLayout, using `NSLayoutConstraint`s. Here's some sample code (at the moment this is all in `viewDidLoad`, which probably isn't the best thing to do, but I'll leave it up to you to organise the code.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //  1.
    var topView: UIView = self.view

    // Have as many labels as you want!
    for i in 0..<numberOfLabels {
        let label = UILabel()

        //  2.
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        //  3.
        if i == 0 || i == numberOfLabels - 1 {
            label.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.abs(1000), forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical)
        }

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        //  4.
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0)

        //  5.
        let attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = i == 0 ? .Top : .Bottom
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: topView, attribute: attribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        //  6.
        if i == numberOfLabels - 1 {
            let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            self.view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
        }

        label.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        self.view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        self.view.addConstraint(topConstraint)

        topView = label
    }
}
```

**1.** `topView` is the view that the `label`'s `NSLayoutAttribute.Top` will be related to. For example: the first label's top is related to its container view; the second label's top is related to the first label; the third label's top is related to the second view, and so on.

**2.** Set the number of lines to zero to allow for as many lines as required by `label.text`.

**3.** Set the content hugging priority of the top and bottom labels to `1000`. This will cause the top and bottom labels to 'hug' the text because middle label(s), by default, have a hugging priority of `250`.

**4.** Create an `NSLayoutConstraint` that sets the `label` to be higher than 20 points because for `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to be set automatically the width and height of the label must be explicitly defined by `NSLayoutConstraint`s.

**5.** This selects the attribute on `topView` that will pin the `label` to the `topView`. For example: if creating the first `label`, its top is pinned to the top of the container view. Otherwise, the top of the `label` is pinned to the bottom of the label above it.

**6.** If it's the last label, pin its bottom edge to the bottom of the container view.

Here's the result:

[image]

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, right now the top layer is the largest one. If I want to do the opposite, so that the top and bottoms height is equal to the text within the label and the middle has the rest of the width. Did you understand? I´m trying to figure out how to do this any idea?

Comment: I'll have another look at it and get back to you.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I could help! Good luck with whatever you're working on!